# Complete noob creating a secure web database for students and teachers at a small private pre-K/kindergarten?

Tags: database, web-applications, multi-user

I'm starting a project for a small private pre-K/kindergarten school (owned by my wife's family), and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this than starting from scratch. Perhaps someone can point me in a good direction before I spin my wheels too much.

The main reason I took this on is to learn about the process, so if anyone is suggesting I get started in Rails or something, I'm quite happy to do that, but on the other hand if there's something out of the box out there that's in the ballpark similar to Wordpress, it might be better to go with what works before getting in over my head.

I'm not a complete noob in that I understand the basics of databse normalization and I'm quite proficient with VBA, and I'm hoping to come away from this with more knowledge about web applications and having done something useful for the school. Can anyone help me get started with this (admittedly very vaguely described) project?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Good on you for just saying "I'll do it" and figuring it out later, but as this is written now it's a bit too vague for this site, I think.  You might be on to something with WordPress ... maybe look into some plugins to see if there's something that will work.  WordPress is easy enough to start with.  Good luck!

Comment: Try Googling *integrate a custom database in wordpress* for starters.

Comment: John, thank you for your reply. I do realize that I was very vaugue, but this is mainly because I'm not sure where to go.

I'm not sure actual WordPress can do what I need, though. I need to be able to have different user levels, admins, teachers and parents, each with their own level of access. Though now that you mention it, Joomla or Drupal might be closer to the mark. The "integrate a custom database" key phrase was helpful as well.

Comment: I stand corrected ... I thought this would get closed, but I was wrong.  That'll teach me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/). I used it for developing a small web application and it proved quick and relatively easy. It follows the MVC (model view controller) paradigm and offers good database support. It is based on [Python](http://www.python.org/), so it is easy enough to get started if you're new to programming at all.

Comment: Hi Claudio. This looks interesting. I got about halfway through a Python course from MIT's open courseware offerings. This might be a good incentive to finish that as well as being what I need for this specific project. Thanks!  <br/>
(I'd vote your answer up, but apparently I'm too new still.)  
On the other hand, I can't even figure out how to add a line break here...

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm glad you liked it, I think it will perfectly fit your demand. About voting, soon you'll be able to do it, but right now if you consider my answer satisfactory you can choose it as accepted by clicking on the check mark below the up and down arrows.

Comment: Done. Thanks again. (Is that all I need to do to close the question?)

Comment: Yes @AlexNorton. That's it!